# Fade in a table row when it's added to a table

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to add a new row to the end of a table:

```
$('.row-data:last').after('some HTML rows');
```

I want to use something like `.fadeIn("slow")` so each row fades in before it appears but I don't seem to be getting any animation:

```
$('.row-data:last').after('some HTML rows').fadeIn("slow");
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thank you :).

Comment: I've also tried slideDown("slow")...

Comment: table and table elements wont be animated. you should use div or something like that

Comment: try `$('.row-data:last').fadeIn('slow').stop().after('some HTML rows');`

Comment: @Yorgo - You can animate TD's IIRC

Comment: Are you asking about Table rows or standard content rows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rows = $('some HTML rows');
rows.hide();
$('.row-data:last-child').after(rows);
rows.fadeIn("slow");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qdPAe/1/

Comment: You cannot animate Table Rows.

Comment: Nice! The only problem is that a `display:block;` is added to the rows, what messes up wide tables. You need to add a `rows.css('display', 'table-row');` after the fadeIn to prevent this.

Answer (score 5):

Add a row on top of table with a fade background:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('<tr class="anim highlight"><td>new text</td></tr>')
    .hide()
    .prependTo('table tbody')
    .fadeIn("slow")
    .addClass('normal');
});
```

Add background transition animation:

```
.anim {  
  transition: background 5s linear;
}
.highlight{
  background: #FF3333; 
}
.normal {  
  background: transparent;  
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/qdPAe/699/

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the `prependTo` function.

Answer (score 3):

Testing in Chrome, my table row faded in great, albeit messy in other browsers. Your problem stems from not hiding the row you're adding in the first place, then not fading in the elements you wish to see afterwards (be it the row or the cells). I got the following working pretty well:

```
var row = jQuery('<tr><td>test</td><td>row</td></tr>');

row.hide();

jQuery('.row-data:last').after(row);

row.fadeIn(500);
```

Hope this helps! jQuery v1.7 BTW...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply animations to table rows. Animate the TD's. It will be seamless.

//JS

```
function fadeRow(rowSelector, callback)
{
    var childCellsSelector = $(rowSelector).children("td");
    var ubound = childCellsSelector.length - 1;
    var lastCallback = null;

    childCellsSelector.each(function(i)
    {
        // Only execute the callback on the last element.
        if (ubound == i)
            lastCallback = callback

        $(this).fadeIn("slow", lastCallback)

    });
}
```

Then call it like:

```
fadeRow( $('selectorOfTR') );
```

Optionally, you can modify this for hiding/removing rows also. Just supply the remove() call in the callback portion of this script.