# How to fade in new content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that updates data in a table row. It all works perfectly but I'm now trying to figure out how to fade in the new updated table row. How can I fade in  `$("#row_"+num).html(data);`

Thanks.

```
  $( "form" ).submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
            // Get the submit button element
            var btn = $(this).find("button").attr("id");//Find button ID
            var num=btn.slice(3,this.id.length); //Get Unique ID for form 

            var formdata = $("#edit_credit"+num).serialize();//Submit correct form by adding unique id
            $.post('update_credit.php', formdata,
               function(data){
            console.log(data); 
          $(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");//hide accordian
           $("#row_"+num).html(data);//Replace data in row

        });
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in a table row when it's added to a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193894/fade-in-a-table-row-when-its-added-to-a-table)

Comment: you need to share your HTML also

Comment: You can easily adjust your code based on the linked solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do a `fade` on the `html()` function. However, you could write a little workaround.

There are two solutions for this. A `jQuery` solution or a `CSS` solution.

**jQuery solution:**
What you want to do is to `hide` the `tr` first, before the new data gets added. Then after the data has been added, `fadeIn()` the `tr`.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var btn = $("#add");
  var data = "<td>I am the replaced data, oh and i fade in aswell!</td>";
  
  btn.click( function() {
    
    var tr = $("#table tr");
    
    tr.hide(); // First hide the original table-row
    tr.html(data); // When its hidden, add the new data
    tr.fadeIn(300); // Then fade the table row in with the new data
    
  });
});
```

```css
table, table tr, table td {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>I am some sample data :)</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add">Replace `I am some sample data :)`</button>
```

**CSS solution:**
Create a `CSS` `keyframe`. Which animates a `fadeIn`.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var btn = $("#add");
  var data = "<td>I am the replaced data, oh and i fade in aswell!</td>";
  
  btn.click( function() {
    
    var tr = $("#table tr");
    
    tr.addClass("fadeIn"); // Append to fadeIn class.
    tr.html(data); // When its hidden, add the new data
    
  });
});
```

```css
table, table tr, table td {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

table tr.fadeIn {
  animation: fade-in .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>I am some sample data :)</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add">Replace `I am some sample data :)`</button>
```

Comment: I went for the jQuery solution in the end and it worked perfectly. Many thanks.